# Server doesn't start, maybe partition table

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, samba

I really need help, yesterday I installed SAMBA 4 on my server and tried to restart after that, but now the Server doesn't start anymore it freezes everytime at the same point.. During that i also changed the /etc/fstab because the tutorial told so, i changed the options from '/' from "defaults" to "defaults,user_xattr,acl,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1" Is there anything I can do to get the server started again?

[SSH-Log](http://siegertb.de/server.log)

Comment: now i have the fstab like before but when i try to boot only one row more appears: <code> [    8.241844] systemd-udevd[244]: starting version 215 </code>